# Failed to load JavaHL Library.- linux/eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, javahl

While trying to install the Subversion plugin I get this error when Eclipse starts:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
/usr/lib/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0: /usr/lib/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/lib/jni
```

---

environment:

- java version "1.6.0_29"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_29-b11)
- Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.4-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
- Linux debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 16 16:22:28 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

I tried changing my java.library.path to a 64-bit lib but it doesn't help - I still go=et the same error (only last line changes - to a 64-bit path)
Also, I have no idea why it's looking in /usr/lib/jni/ even after I change the java.library.path.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was annoyed by that message so I did this and it disappeared!

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you're being cheeky, but switching the Interface Lib was the winner. Nice one.

Comment: Works and easy fixes like this are why stackoverflow is the best.

Answer (score 7):

To solved just install the package with this command:

> sudo apt-get install libsvn-java

and you must config eclipse.inito add path /jni

example :

> -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni

https://danangindrak.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/solved-memperbaiki-subclipse-error-default-svn-client-not-found-pada-eclipse/

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes. Worked like a charm for me and actually solves the problem instead of circumventing it.

Comment: The biggest headache is when using yum to install subversion-javahl. The installation folder is not visible at first. Use rpm -ql to find it:
'$yum install subversion-javahl
    $rpm -q subversion-javahl
        subversion-javahl-1.9.12-1.x86_64
    $ rpm -ql subversion-javahl
        /usr/lib64/libsvnjavahl-1.so
        /usr/lib64/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0
        /usr/lib64/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
        /usr/lib64/svn-javahl/svn-javahl.jar'

Answer (score 1):

OK I just ran into the same problem. I installed the javaHL lib but that didn't fix it alone. I was able to fix it by double checking which version of subversion I had installed in synaptic. I actually had 1.6.x while I installed the subclipse for version 1.8.x. so I started over, deleted my eclipse folder, extracted it and installed subclipse from the following eclipse update site:  http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

more on the incompatibility:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA
(get the one that says Links for 1.6.x Release:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have libsvn-java installed. To solved just install the package with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvn-java
```

and you are read use subclipse.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved - the reason was that 64b Subversive SVN Connectors that were installed couldn't work with 32b JDK; I've re-installed eclipse to 32b version and everything is ok

Comment: Why not install a 64-bit JDK?

Comment: to be fair, I don't rememder - that was last March.. But I think, both variants are possible)